# Session is handled by server or language?

Tags: php

i am working on PHP and i know how to manage the session. But my question is, session is related to language or web server. Who  is responsible to execute the ***session***?

Comment: Why i am getting negative mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are responsible for session execute by starting the session with session_start().

By default session is stored in  /tmp on a Linux/Unix system. You can change it with session_save_path() method.

Also take a look in php.ini for [Session] part, it should look like this

```
; Handler used to store/retrieve data.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler
session.save_handler = files
```

As You can see by default it is stored as file storage, it's recommended to move session to cache i.e. memcache.

EDIT:

Maybe this post can help You: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/19054

Answer (score 0):

A session token is a unique identifier that is generated and sent from a server to a client to identify the current interaction session. The client usually stores and sends the token as an HTTP cookie and/or sends it as a parameter in GET or POST queries. The reason to use session tokens is that the client only has to handle the identifier—all session data is stored on the server (usually in a database, to which the client does not have direct access) linked to that identifier. Examples of the names that some programming languages use when naming their HTTP cookie include JSESSIONID (JSP), PHPSESSID (PHP), CGISESSID (CGI), and ASPSESSIONID (ASP).

Comment: Please consider adding a reference to the source of that paragraph

Comment: my question is Who is responsible to execute the session?

Comment: @ravikant . It must be the server

Comment: Stated in his awnser in the first sentence, the server is.

Comment: What do you mean by "execute" ?? The webserver doesn't do it. PHP handles a PHP session. The webserver simply forwards the HTTP request and response containing the `Set-Cookie` and `Cookie` header (but sessions can be also used without cookies).

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are a combination of **two components**, namely, a **client-side session** ID and **server-side session data**. well, practically it behaves like a cookie, 2 cookies which reply on each other. The Client-side can send a session ID to the server-side as a URL param, cookie, or even HTTP headers. The server then uses this session ID to find the matching session data to return to the requesting client.

so to answer your question straight up, a session is part of both the server and the client, which you maybe refer to as language. But PHP handles the **execution**.

**additionally**, You can tweak session behavior via the various [session functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php).

Comment: How did you find out "language" refers to "client"... for me it sounded like he ment "language" referring to "PHP".

Comment: PHP is handling the session and PHP is not the client.

Comment: yes you are right my friend, php handles session and php is in the server side. though a part of session is stored in the client in this case the browser. thanks for clarifying

Answer (score -1):

Session is generated by server but it is coupled with the language. So if you look into your browser resource you'll find your session id prefixed with the language you are using.

Comment: Vice versa. It's generated by PHP and *coupled* / delivered through the webserver.